# How can I access property on object of type T, when T is a generic class with unknown parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method in an interface that works on objects of parameter type T. One implementation requires access to a property on type T, and in this implementation T is expected to be of type `ClassA<TC>` where TC is an unknown parameter type. The property I need to access is on `ClassA` itself.

How can I access this Foo.Property in a type safe way ? Is it possible? I know I can do it using dynamics, but I would like to know if there's a different way. I've tried IsAssignableFrom and other checks, but cant seem to get it working.

```
interface IFace {
    void Request<T>(T foo);
}

class ClassA<T> {
    public int Property;
}

class ClassB : IFace {
    public void Request<T>(T foo) {
    // I want to assert that Foo is of ClassA, and access the property. 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to make `ClassA` implement an interface which defines the property you want, and then constrain `T` to that interface.

Any members of the constraints can be accessed. You could reflect on 'T' and hope the property is there, but you'd have no way to be sure. An interface exists specifically to define that some functionality is implemented by an arbitrary type, and is therefore almost certainly what you're looking for.

Comment: Normally you could do this directly on the class, but since ClassA has a generic as well, this is your best bet.

Comment: But this constraint would need to be on IFace.Request, right? The problem is, only one of many implementations of this interface expects objects of classA, and needs access to the property.

Comment: @eZet: That indicates an even larger issue, then:  you shouldn't be using generics, but rather overloads. The point of generics is that you don't care about the exact type, or want to use any type with some constraint. If you want a method for a specific class, the method should not be generic.

Comment: I guess I have to reconsider how to solve this. The thing is, all other implementations of Request do not rely on the type of T at all. It is just that one implementation, where T should always be of ClassA, that I actually need to access T.

Comment: @eZet: The problem is even larger then. You can certainly cast the instance of `T` to `ClassA`, but you have to think about the fact that you're now changing the public API for this single implementation. This implies that `ClassB` doesn't *really* implement `IFace`, but just pretends to. This will definitely require some careful thought.

Comment: @Magus: "This implies that ClassB doesn't really implement IFace, but just pretends to." True, I will make another Interface for Request<T>(T foo) where T : ClassA; For the record, how exactly can I cast T to ClassA with an unknown parameter ? Also, how can I check that T is of type ClassA<> ?

Comment: @eZet: You can use the `.GetType()` method on the instance and do a comparison, but because `ClassA<T>` is also generic, the cast will be difficult and involve reflection. You should be able to inspect the type, but I'd suggest scrapping the attempt to implement `IFace` if possible. Any solution where you don't will be messy.

Comment: Yes, I'll be making another interface for the specific case as I mentioned. But as an answer to the original question and for learning, I'd like to find out how I would actually do the casts and use `.GetType()` for this check. I tried casting it to ClassA<object> but that doesn't work.

Comment: You should probably open another question for that, though there may be an answer available somewhere else. Still, while reflection can be very useful, I'd avoid it where possible (partly because it's slow, partly because its messy, and mostly because it's mostly useful when you're misusing the type system (attributes notwithstanding))